# Best way to do an iteration scheme

Tags: for-loop, wolfram-mathematica, iteration

I hope this hasn't been asked before, if so I apologize.

*EDIT: For clarity, the following notation will be used: boldface uppercase for matrices, boldface lowercase for vectors, and italics for scalars.*

Suppose **x0** is a vector, **A** and **B** are matrix functions, and **f** is a vector function.

I'm looking for the best way to do the following iteration scheme in Mathematica:

```
A0 = A(x0), B0=B(x0), f0 = f(x0)
x1 = Inverse(A0)(B0.x0 + f0)

A1 = A(x1), B1=B(x1), f1 = f(x1)
x2 = Inverse(A1)(B1.x1 + f1)

...
```

I know that a `for-loop` can do the trick, but I'm not quite familiar with Mathematica, and I'm concerned that this is the most efficient way to do it. This is a justified concern as I would like to define a function `u(N):=xN`and use it in further calculations.

I guess my questions are:

What's the most efficient way to program the scheme?

Is `RecurrenceTable` a way to go?

**EDIT**

It was a bit more complicated than I tought. I'm providing more details in order to obtain a more thorough response.

Before doing the recurrence, I'm having problems understanding how to program the functions **A**, **B** and **f**.

Matrices **A** and **B** are functions of the time step *dt = 1/T* and the space step *dx = 1/M*, where *T* and *M* are the number of points in the {*0 < x < 1*, *0 < t*} region. This is also true for vector the function **f**.

The dependance of **A**, **B** and **f** on **x** is rather tricky:

**A** and **B** are *upper* and *lower triangular* matrices (like a *tridiagonal* matrix; I suppose we can call them *multidiagonal*), with defined constant values on their diagonals.

Given a point *0 < xs < 1*, I need to determine it's representative *xn* in the mesh (the closest), and *then* substitute the *nth* row of **A** and **B** with the function **v**( **x**) (transposed, of course), and the *nth* row of **f** with the function *w*( **x**).

Summarizing, **A** = **A**(*dt*, *dx*, *xs*, **x**). The same is true for **B** and **f**.

Then I need do the loop mentioned above, to define **u**( **x**) = `step[T]`.

Hope I've explained myself.

Comment: Does `f` map vectors to numbers? And `A` and `B`, are they mappings which can be represented by matrices (vector-vector mappings), or matrix-valued functions (vector-matrix mappings), or functions of matrices (matrix-number mappings)?

Comment: ``x`` is a vector in say, ``Rn``, ``f:Rn -> Rn``, ``A,B:Rn -> Rn x Rn``. And all the scheme is numerical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best method, but I'd just use plain old memoization. You can represent an individual step as

```
xstep[x_] := Inverse[A[x]](B[x].x + f[x])
```

and then

```
u[0] = x0
u[n_] := u[n] = xstep[u[n-1]]
```

If you know how many values you need in advance, and it's advantageous to precompute them all for some reason (e.g. you want to open a file, use its contents to calculate `xN`, and then free the memory), you could use `NestList`. Instead of the previous two lines, you'd do

```
xlist = NestList[xstep, x0, 10];
u[n_] := xlist[[n]]
```

This will break if `n > 10`, of course (obviously, change 10 to suit your actual requirements).

Of course, it may be worth looking at your specific functions to see if you can make some algebraic simplifications.

Comment: The matrices are almost constants, but as the scheme is intended to be numerical, it doesn't matter. Should've clarified it in the question. Let me take a look at your answer at home, ``tic-toc`` it against a ``for-loop``, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ended up using your solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write a function that accepts A0, B0, x0, and f0, and then returns A1, B1, x1, and f1 - say

```
step[A0_?MatrixQ, B0_?MatrixQ, x0_?VectorQ, f0_?VectorQ] := Module[...]
```

I would then `Nest` that function.  It's hard to be more precise without more precise information.

Also, if your procedure is numerical, then you certainly don't want to compute `Inverse[A0]`, as this is not a numerically stable operation.  Rather, you should write

```
A0.x1 == B0.x0+f0
```

and then use a numerically stable solver to find `x1`.  Of course, Mathematica's `LinearSolve` provides such an algorithm.

Comment: It'd be useful to have `step` take a list, e.g. `step[{A0_, ...}]`, to be able to use it more easily in `Nest`.

Comment: More details are provided in first EDIT. ``LinearSolve`` is a great suggestion; I suppose it works like the ``\`` operator in MATLAB.